# How to handle DragLeave event of a Form separated from the DragEnter events of its subcontrols?

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I have a Form that should catch the DragDrop, DragEnter, DragLeave events. The form has many subcontrols and when the user drags directly over the form and then over a subcontrol of the form, the DragLeave event of the form is raised. I would like to handle the DragLeave event of the form (when the user drags outside the form) separated from the DragLeave events generated when the mouse starts to hover a subcontrol which may also handle drag & drop events.

I read the official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.dragleave) and I still do not know what to do.

In the designer I create two panels, one inside another, keeping a space between the form's border and the outermost panel, and between the outermost panel's margin and the innermost panel. The form and the panels all have `AllowDrop = true`.

[image: screenshot]

Code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    AllowDrop = true;
}

protected override void OnDragLeave(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnDragLeave(e);

    Debug.WriteLine("OnDragLeave called");
}
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Start dragging a file and while dragging move the cursor over the form.
2. Move the cursor outside the form.
3. In the Output panel in Visual Studio a new line is printed: `OnDragLeave called`.
4. When the cursor is directly over the form, move it to hover the outermost panel.
5. In the Output panel in Visual Studio a new line is printed: `OnDragLeave called`.

Expected:

- Only the output of the step 3 above should be shown, not of the step 5.

**Update:** I an trying to show an overlay over the entire form when the mouse drags a file over the form. The overlay is created and tested and so are the other drag events.

Comment: Can you explain what's the use of this? It's easier to suggest something, knowing what you want to achieve. Btw, you could simply check the Curson position, to check whether the mouse has moved outside the Form's bounds. In the `DragLeave` event: `Console.WriteLine(this.Bounds.Contains(Cursor.Position));`

Comment: @Jimi Thank you. It Works. You can post an answer if you wish. I updated the question with more details.

Comment: Sure, I can do that. But, after you have added an overlay (*which covers the entire Form*), can your Form still raise Mouse events? Are you leaving some empty space, near the Form's borders, maybe?

Comment: @Jimi More precisely, the overlay is inside the Form and it has the Size the same as the ClientSize of the Form. The overlay also appears when dragging a file over the Form's title bar.

Comment: So, is it the overlay that receives/handles the Mouse and the Drop event events after it's shown?

Comment: @Jimi The overlay is made visible on DragEnter and disappears after processing on DragDrop or on DragLeave. The handlers for these three events are associated with all the controls in the Form, including the Form.